# Smart contract to exchange old bep20 tokens for new ones

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, bsc, pancakeswap, binance

I've created two Bep20 tokens (old/new) and I was wondering if I could write a smart contract that exchanges/swaps old tokens for new ones.

Is there a simple way to exchange two Bep20 tokens using a smart contract?

Any guidance, related links would help a ton. (Hope the question is not too flat).

Comment: What did you try? The obvious solution of sending the old tokens to the contract, and the contract minting new tokens should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below code

```
// swap 1:1 
function swap(uint256 amount) external {
        
        IERC20(tokenA).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(0), amount);  // I am buring the token A by sending it to zero address, you can modify the to address
        IERC20(tokenB).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        
        emit Swapped(msg.sender, amount);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I've found a different solution as well